# 406 Not Acceptable: Spring 3.2 + JSON + AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, spring-mvc

Searched tons of sites and even stackoverflow but have not found a solution to this problem. Looks like lot of people have encountered this problem but its seems a unified solution is missing that encompasses all the aspect. Have already spent 1.5 days on it.

I see the method is getting invoked but somewhere `@ResponseBody` is not getting translated properly. Can someone take a look and let me know what the problem is. I have Uploaded the code on github. [Link to source code on github](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find_user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<String> findUser(@RequestParam("term") String name) {
    log.info("Search string for user name: " + name);   
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    users.add("Sam");
    users.add("Dan");
    return users;
}
```

Browser screen shot below with 406 response

[image]

**Please note: Ah! How painful. This setup works with Spring 3.1.4 and not with 3.2.X**

Comment: Can't check out you code for personal reason, but for 1 thing, why you add jackson jar? seems spring can meet your requirement.

Comment: @OQJF you are correct. There is no need to do add these jars [`jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2 and jackson-core-asl-1.9.12`] but the effect without these jars is still the same. Still get `406` error.

Comment: When I get home, I will check out your code and check the reason, anyway I think it's just a tiny mistake.

Comment: how did it work, shall i downgrade, its real pain, someone help, same problem, i added jackson mapper aswell jackson core, but still same problem, is it spring issue? r u sure? please reply

Comment: Its not a Spring issue. I was able to make it work. Recently it has stopped working and in couple of days I will try to make this work again. Note: What I have uploaded and said should make everything work. I can share notes if I find something new.

Comment: @user2003821 Are you returning a List or just a String? It seems the return String works with 200 status and List gives 406 status. Do you mind letting me know.

Comment: i was returning a list of String

Comment: @java_dude did you make it working with 3.2?

Comment: Okay I tested and the setup works with 3.1.4 and not with 3.2.X. Please downgrade. Have no patience for making and testing it to make it work with 3.2.x. Pure waste of time.

Comment: same problem is here please suggest me, i am using spring 4.0.2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477169/unable-to-get-list-into-ajax-response-from-spring-mvc?noredirect=1#comment62451939_37477169

Answer (score 5, accepted):

God, it almost kills me. I tried whatever I can, still stuck there. But finally I figured it out. The reason is Spring, download Spring 3.1.1 and replace all the jars with 3.1.1jars, and it works. All your config is good.

Comment: But whats wrong with Spring 3.2 version? [link] (http://blog.springsource.org/2012/12/13/spring-framework-3-2-goes-ga/)

Comment: Check out the link.. http://blog.springsource.org/2012/12/13/spring-framework-3-2-goes-ga/          They say upgrade. Ah!! I will downgrade. Thanks. Will try that soon.

Comment: Several releases have this issue, seems it's still there.

Comment: Thanks again for looking into this. Downloading previous version of Spring.

Comment: Please note: This setup is working for me now.. Just add Jackson jar files back in.

Comment: Simply works. It's weird that even this stuff is not yet fixed in 3.2.3.RELEASE :S

Comment: Grr ... Spent almost half a day just to get this fixed.

Comment: can you tell me please how to fix this problem in 3.2.5. I have also same problem. Please help to solve it. Now i don't want to change my spring version.

Comment: i am using spring 4.0.2 but still getting this 406 (Not Acceptable) error..
here is my question link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477169/unable-to-get-list-into-ajax-response-from-spring-mvc?noredirect=1#comment62451939_37477169]

Answer (score 2):

I also faced up with a same problem. After debugging Spring I found that `ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy` tries to determine media type based on an extension in the URL. (Probably, because it cannot deduce what media type it should return from `Accept` header which contained `*/*` in my case.)

So, one of the way to fix this is to rename URL in mapping by replacing `.html` by `.json`.

Comment: Correct answer with a useful fact !!