# 406 Not Acceptable error while making an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have the below code snippet in one of my .js.coffee files:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/attachinary_files/' + id
      method: 'put'
      }).done(//do something)
```

In my browser console I get the error:

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

I am unable to find the reason. I have required the necessary files in my application.js file, like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I am unable to find what I am missing. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks:)

Edit:

controller

```
def update
    super
    attachinary_file = AttachinaryFile.find(params[:id])
    AttachinaryFile.where(attachinariable_id: attachinary_file.attachinariable_id)
      .update_all(is_primary: false)
    attachinary_file.update_column(:is_primary, true)
    respond_to do |format|
      flash.now[:notice] = nil
    end
  end
```

Comment: What do your routes say for this? And your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Verify that your controller accept js calls

2) In your JS code, specify that you want a JS formatted result, with headers or with the url :

`url: '/attachinary_files/' + id + '.js'`

3) If it's not enough, in your controller, specify what you return for JS :

```
respond_to do |format|
  flash.now[:notice] = nil
  format.js { render js: "alert('Hello Rails');" }
end
```

Comment: thanks. This works fine, but if I remove the alert, I will have to create a .js partial? Am I right?

Comment: yes, a partial will be needed if you don't inline the response

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the content type which is the reason for [`HTTP 406`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) error.

Update your ajax code to include data-type of the response:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/attachinary_files/' + id
  method: 'put'
  dataType: 'script'
}).done(//do something)
```

Please reference [Data-Type (with jQuery)](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Spring 3.2.5 and got this error.
Resolved by using 3.1.1

[406 Not Acceptable: Spring 3.2 + JSON + AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672848/406-not-acceptable-spring-3-2-json-ajax)