# jquery Ajax not working with Spring 3.2.3

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

**I am trying to learn SPRING MVC + Jquery Ajax but I am getting this error on ajax success, Following is my code configuration**

**jQuery Ajax.**

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"" +attr.url +"",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success:function(response){
                            console.log("Response length",response.length);
                        },
                        error:function(e){
                        }
                    });
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/getList.htm", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<SomeClass> _giveList(HttpServletResponse response) throws DaException{
        List<SomeClass>someClass = iSomeClass.getData();
        return someClass;
    }
```

**This method is executing and I can see the size of someClass.
jackObjectMapper configuration in applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"></bean>
    <bean id="jacksonMessageChanger" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
    <ref bean = "jacksonMessageChanger"/>
    </list>
    </property>
     </bean>
```

**`jackson dependency in POM.xml`**

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>
```

The controller method is executing but there is no response in ajax request.So I am not seeing the console log of the ajax success function.
But I am getting this error

The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
I tried to resolve this by also adding headers = "application/json".But no luck. 
Any help will be truly appreciable.

Comment: Jquery is a front end and Spring MVC is backend, its nothing to do with those frameworks.. You're returning something called `shoppingBrandMasters` , I can't seem to find it in your controller..

Comment: Have changed the return type. Sorry for that mistake.You can take out some time and google jquery ajax and SPRING MVC communication

Comment: What I meant is, your question seems to blame either Jquery Ajax or Spring MVC as it is not working with other one. Actually it's working, that's why you're getting the error response, but the error is due to the problem in user codes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is a typical when the spring mvc framework fails to convert representation (in your case `json`)  from/to java object. This can happen on account of an error in configuring converter, or an error in the process.

Your case is the former, with `Spring 3.x` you should remove your current jackson dependencies and use e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

`com.fasterxml.jackson` is the package used for `jackson 2.x` which is being used by `Spring 4.x` versions.

With your current code, the effect is the same as not having `jackson` dependencies at all, which are in charge for conversion json/java conversion, and that is why you're getting your error

Comment: I already tried that but it didnt helped at all. Have also modified the POM file ... now you see the jackson dependencies I am using

Comment: `org.codehaus.jackson` deps are the ones you should keep for your version, so remove the `com.fasterxml.jackson`, that's surely wrong. You should check one more thing, that your `SomeClass` is a valid POJO, having an erroneus setters/getters would give you the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do you expecting the response data to be in JSON?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"" +attr.url +"",

    // contentType is the type of data you're sending, Since you're not sending any
    // data, I assume you expect the response to be in JSON format, so you need
    // to change it to dataType: "json"
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:function(response){
        console.log("Response length",response.length);
    },
    error:function(e){
    }
});
```

So if you're expecting the list of data to be in JSON format, you probably need to tell your Contoller about its `produces` type. You don't need to explicitly specify this, as you've already defined JacksonObjectMapper, but just try it.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/getList.htm", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
                                                                 // ^ It's not necessary to specify like this, but just try it
public @ResponseBody List<SomeClass> _giveList(HttpServletResponse response) throws DaException{
    List<SomeClass>someClass = iSomeClass.getData();
    return someClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem from this post.[406 Not Acceptable: Spring 3.2 + JSON + AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672848/406-not-acceptable-spring-3-2-json-ajax)
I replaced .htm by .son and it worked. I dont know what is problem with spring 3. with .htm