# Unable to get List into ajax response from Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Unable to get List into ajax response from Spring MVC getting 406 (Not Acceptable)  but able to get String, here my code

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Info> initCategory(@ModelAttribute(value = "getCategories") Info info) {
    List<Info> category = null;
    try {
        category = infoService.getCategory(info.getPlantName());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return category;
}
```

Ajax

```
    function selectCategory() {
        var plantId = $('#plantId').val();
        alert(plantId);
        $.ajax({
                    url : '/veQNL/addPro/getCategory',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : $("#addProject").serialize(),
                    success : function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
        });
}
```

and dispatcher

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
<!--registration and scanning all controller ,service ,repository annotation -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ve.qnl" />
<!-- jdbc resource -->

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
    cache-period="31556926" />
<mvc:annotation-driven /></beans>
```

Have try many things Like Map,Json etc but getting the same, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  406 (Not Acceptable) on browser console... !

Comment: Can you post your spring mvc config?

Comment: @codependent please check my updated question.

Comment: That's only the beginning of the config...

Comment: @codependent please check updated xml...!

Comment: try changing header to this: headers = "Accept=application/json"

Comment: no effect @Sampada

Comment: if this is Spring 3 or above, you will need to remove the headers attribute and add this: consumes="application/json" . Ref: http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements/

Comment: @Sampada just read out the 5th Point now i am getting  
415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: Do you have jackson in your classpath?

Comment: @codependent yes i have included jackson Jar also.....

Comment: if i use String instead of List<Info> and return any String then it works for me but i want to send list instead of string...!

Comment: since this is a POST method, you will have to add "consumes" .

Comment: if i use consumes = "application/json" then the rest java code is not working... i mean it's preventing to proceed the java code,should i change in ajax also, please look into ajax..!

Comment: you mean the program control goes thru to the java code? you are able to debug?

Comment: Yeah the scenario is i am calling ajax from JSP page and it hit to java class and fetch some records and it returns back to ajax... if i get the data into String and send back then the ajax get the response properly but if i get the data inside List then the ajax is not responding... that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add the following bean to your configuration:

```
<bean id="jacksonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
```

Comment: What about the id="jacksonConverter" , where it used ?

Comment: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException,

Comment: I would suggest debugging in `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` -> `protected <T> void writeWithMessageConverters(T returnValue, MethodParameter returnType,ServletServerHttpRequest inputMessage, ServletServerHttpResponse outputMessage)`. Check that you have a Jackson message converter, the media types etc.